# Breakpoints doesn't work in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 ultimate and I have some problems after reinstalling. Breakpoints don't work in any type of project, even console application. I just start debugging and have new tab "source code is unavailable" with title "code isn't executing" and text "in current thread any code isn't executed now, or call stack is unavailable".. Also this situation appears when any unhandled exception is thrown, I can't read exception message, just this tab

Comment: Try cleaning your project, rebuilding. Are you doing anything special such as debugging through multiple languages? When did it stop working?

Answer (score 0):

Delete .sou file from your solution directory. This method resolve my issue.